# Populate an Array Adapter using Retrofit

Tags: android, android-listview, retrofit

I am fairly new to Android development and just discovered Retrofit today. I am hoping to build an Android app that consumes my site's API and it looks like Retrofit fits the bill nicely.

I am trying to populate a ListView with data returned in the form of JSON from my API but cannot figure out exactly what I need to do. I have successfully populated the ListView with dummy data directly in my code (sorry, lots of code):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "App";
    public static ListView mListView;
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersListView);


        populateUserList(); // Add items to the Users array
        populateListView(); // Add the Users to the List View
    }

    // Add items to the User List array
    // This is what I want to populate from my API
    private void populateUserList() {
        users.add(new User("Joe Smith", "jsmith@nowhere.com"));
        users.add(new User("Frank Smith", "fsmith@somewhere.net"));
        users.add(new User("Mary Jane", "mjane@website.org"));
    }

    //Add the Users Array to the List View
    private void populateListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = new UserListAdapter();
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private class UserListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
        public UserListAdapter(){
            super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.user_item, users);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            // Check if Item View is null
            if (itemView == null)
            {
                // Need to create a new view - make sure we have a view to work with.
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false);
            }

            // Find the user to work with
            User currentUser = users.get(position);

            // Fill the view
            TextView nameField = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_nameField);
            TextView emailField = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_emailView);

            nameField.setText(currentUser.getName());
            emailField.setText(currentUser.getEmail());

            return itemView;
        }
    }
```

Here is my API code for Retrofit:

```
public interface Api {
    @GET("/httplist")
    List<User> userList();
}
```

.. and my Rest Client:

```
public class RestClient {

    private static Api REST_CLIENT;
    private static String ROOT = "https://somewhere.org";
    static {
        setupRestClient();
    }
    private RestClient() {}
    public static Api get() {
        return REST_CLIENT;
    }

    private static void setupRestClient() {
        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ROOT)
                .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
        RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();
        REST_CLIENT = restAdapter.create(Api.class);
    }
}
```

.. the User class ..

```
public class User {
        private String name;
        private String email;

        public User(String name, String email) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
    }
```

Finally, some simple JSON I am trying to handle:

```
[
{"name":"John Smith","email":"jsmith@somewhere.net"}
...
]
```

I feel like I'm close but I just can't seem to hook it up. Help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

**UPDATE**
First stab at doing this. I had to put the API request in a Runnable to avoid a NetworkOnMainThread exception. The items are not being added.

```
private void populateUserList() {
        users.add(new User("Joe Smith", "jsmith@nowhere.com"));
        users.add(new User("Frank Smith", "fsmith@somewhere.net"));
        users.add(new User("Mary Jane", "mjane@website.org"));
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    users = RestClient.get().userList();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

Comment: Have you implemented a User class?

Comment: Yes, see update - sorry I missed that!

Comment: Can you try removing the constructor ... I don't see why I would be a problem, but I noticed I generally don't have any constructors for these classes

Comment: Removing the constructor from the User class crashes the app. Where I'm stuck here is how to take the returned List from my API call and attach it to my ArrayAdapter/ListView..

Comment: Ahhhh I see what you mean. No, I probably wouldn't have a constructor for Retrofit.. but it is required to make the app work with the sample items added to the Users list. I haven't figured out where to start with attaching the Retrofit list.

Comment: were do you actually call the userList() method, am I missing that?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out exactly how I would go about that. I'll post my first attempt in an update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67649/discussion-between-nightmicu-and-npn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use asynchronous version of your REST method, provided by Retrofit. This frees you from creating a separate background thread for the network operation and keeps your code cleaner. When you have your users list, update adapter. Your don't need a separate users array.

```
private void populateUserList() {
  RestClient.get().userList(new Callback<List<User>>() {
    public void success(List<User> users, Response response) {
      // this is called in main thread so it's ok to update views
      mUsersAdapter.clear();
      mUsersAdapter.addAll(users);
    } 
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
      // handle error
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This looks promising but I'm still running into a brick wall. I have tried several different things in the past half an hour or so and keep receiving errors essentially saying that I cannot manipulate things created on a different thread (I'm assuming this refers to the ListView or ArrayAdapter). I tried just making the callback for the API request and received the following error - `Api.userList: Must have return type or Callback as last argument, not both.`

Comment: It's less than ideal but I just populated my ListView! The solution was changing my Api @GET to `@GET("/httplist")
    void userList(Callback<List<User>> callback);` - the `void` is the key here. Since you got me on the right path, I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: And I say "less than ideal" because of the sloppy code I added during my desperate attempts - not your solution. That's very ideal. ;)